# Run the webrtc/samples test and I got errs 'Cannot read property serviceKey of undefined', like as the following:

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have trouble to build https://github.com/webrtc/samples in win 7.
 I am following the steps of [this Doc](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/test/README.md).
 But there are some errors like as the following.

```
D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\test>node server.js
D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\test\server.js:20
key: keys.serviceKey,
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceKey' of undefined
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\test\server.js:20:14
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:278:24
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:168:24
at done (D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:78:24)
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:91:13
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:1044:20
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:1027:9
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:937:20
at D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\lib\pem.js:1092:20
at F (D:\demo\webrtcDemo\samples\node_modules\pem\node_modules\which\which.j
s:68:16)
```

Thanks for any reply ^o^ !!!

Comment: Try to add `console.log(keys)` above `var options` to check if serviceKey or similar name exist in Key object in server.js file!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved that by installing OpenSSL in my machine.
I was using Windows 10 and this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYLTtABP1F4 worked for me.

It is important to setup Environment variables. One last step is to setup config.cnf file in Environment Variables. I had xampp so the path for that is "C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf".

Set variable name : `OPENSSL_CONF`

and variable value : `C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf`

In Linux(I used Ubuntu) it is easy, just follow these instructions : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110429
and set `config.cnf` file as per your server.